# Функция с неопределенным количеством параметров

Tags: c, функции, параметры

Мне нужно создать функцию, которая считает выражение: (х1 + х3 + х5 + ...) / (х2 + х4 + х6 + ...) (х1 - хn - параметры функции). Количество параметров чётное и они имеют разный тип, при вызове функции я перед каждым числом указываю его тип. Я использовала макрокоманды из библиотеки stdarg.h, но результат почему-то неверный (inf, хотя должно быть 0.75), не могу понять, что делаю неправильно:

```
void SumArg(int, ...);

void main(void)
{
    system("chcp 1251");
    SumArg(6, 'i', 1, 'd', 2.0, 'i', 3, 'd', 4.0, 'i', 5.0, 'd', 6.0);
    getchar(); getchar();
}
void SumArg(int k, ...)
{
    va_list p;
    va_start(p, k);
    double sum = 0;
    double a = 0; // числитель
    double b = 0; // знаменатель
    int xi;
    double xd;
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        switch (*p) {
        case 'i': {
            xi = va_arg(++p, int);
            if (i % 2 == 0)
                a = a + xi;
            else
                b = b + xi;
            break;
        }
        case 'd': {
            xd = va_arg(++p, double);
            if (i % 2 == 0)
                a = a + xd;
            else
                b = b + xd;
            break;
        }
        }
        p++;
    }
    va_end(p);
    sum = a / b;
    printf(" Сумма: %lf\n", sum);
}
```

Comment: А зачем вы `++p` в `va_arg` делаете? См. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic/va_arg

Comment: @Harry потому что проверяю (i или d) елемент по адресу р, а хi или хd присваиваю елемент, что стоит после буквы типа, по адресу р + 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если уж вы так хотите, чтоб не собирать все числа просто в `double` (ну, может, вы тренируетесь...), то хотя бы верно указывайте типы:

```
SumArg(6, 'i', 1, 'd', 2.0, 'i', 3, 'd', 4.0, 'i', 5.0, 'd', 6.0);
```

Какое тут у вас число идет после последнего `i`? 5.0 - целое?

И еще - никакие `++p` не нужны - читайте [документацию](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic/va_arg)!!

В вашем варианте функция должна иметь вид

```
void main(void)
{
    SumArg(6, 'i', 1, 'd', 2.0, 'i', 3, 'd', 4.0, 'i', 5, 'd', 6.0);
    getchar(); getchar();
}
void SumArg(int k, ...)
{
    va_list p;
    va_start(p, k);
    double sum = 0;
    double a = 0; // числитель
    double b = 0; // знаменатель
    int xi;
    double xd;
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        char c = va_arg(p,char);
        switch (c) {
        case 'i': {
            xi = va_arg(p, int);
            if (i % 2 == 0)
                a = a + xi;
            else
                b = b + xi;
            break;
        }
        case 'd': {
            xd = va_arg(p, double);
            if (i % 2 == 0)
                a = a + xd;
            else
                b = b + xd;
            break;
        }
        }
    }
    va_end(p);
    sum = a / b;
    printf(" Сумма: %lf\n", sum);
}
```

Но проще, без мороки и т.д. - просто передавать все числа как `double`, дописав точку :)

Ну или хотя бы так:

```
void SumArg(int k, ...)
{
    va_list p;
    va_start(p, k);
    double sum = 0;
    double a = 0; // числитель
    double b = 0; // знаменатель
    double xd;
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        char c = va_arg(p,char);
        assert(c=='i' || c=='d');    // Или иная проверка, или default с сообщением об ошибке
        switch (c) {
        case 'i': {
            xd = va_arg(p, int);
            break;
        }
        case 'd': {
            xd = va_arg(p, double);
            break;
        }
        }

        if (i%2 == 0)
            a += xd;
        else
            b += xd;
    }
    va_end(p);
    sum = a / b;
    printf(" Сумма: %lf\n", sum);
}
```