# Функция с неопределенным количеством параметров (без использования stdarg.h)

Tags: c, функции, параметры

Мне нужно создать функцию, которая считает выражение:

```
(х1 + х3 + х5 + ...) / (х2 + х4 + х6 + ...)
```

где `х1`-`хn` - параметры функции. Количество параметров чётное и они имеют разный тип, при вызове функции я перед каждым числом указываю его тип. Я написала функцию, используя макросы из `<stdarg.h>` (см. вопрос [Функция с неопределенным количеством параметров](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1092637/%d0%a4%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2)).

Как можно выполнить это же задание, не используя макросы из `<stdarg.h>`, а используя только указатели? Вот приблизительно такое написала:

```
void SumIntDouble(int, ...);

void main(void)
{
    system("chcp 1251");
    SumIntDouble(6, 'i', 1, 'd', 2.0, 'i', 3, 'd', 4.0, 'i', 5, 'd', 6.0);
    getchar(); getchar();
}

void SumIntDouble(int k, ...)
{
    double sum = 0;
    double a = 0; // числитель
    double b = 0; // знаменатель
    int* p = &k + 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        switch (*p) {
        case'i': {
            p += sizeof(char);
            if (i % 2 == 0)
                a += *p;
            else
                b += *p;
            p++;
            break;
        }
        case'd': {
            p += sizeof(char);
            if (i % 2 == 0)
                a += *(double*)p;
            else
                b += *(double*)p;
            p += 2; // сдвигаем на double (=2 int)
            break;
        }
        }
    }
    sum = a / b;
    printf(" Сумма: %lf\n", sum);
}
```

Comment: Без `<stdarg.h>` *законными* способами никак не получится. Это магия компилятора.

Comment: @eanmos Я прекрасно это понимаю, жаль, что преподавателям этого не объяснишь) Нужно написать вариант функции без <stdarg.h>

Comment: какой результат то получается ??

Comment: ну навскидку могу сказать что указатель p ты используешь неверно

Comment: @Slavik Результат 0.5 вместо 0.75, если вам о чем-то это говорит) По задумке указатель стоит на первом необязательном параметре (тип елемента), далее я его двигаю через один елемент, а елементы, которые стоят после указателя, суммирую, учитывая их тип (по крайней мере так должно быть)

Comment: Такой подход может сработать, только если компилятор передает все аргументы через стек. В общем, надо откомпилировать в ассемблер (например, командой `gcc -S prog.c` (в результате получим файл `prog.s`)) и посмотреть его

Comment: @Nastya да ни о чём не говорит,   так от нечего делать спросил )

Comment: @Nastya стоит то он стоит, вот только там где надо он стоит только вначале, когда ты присваиваешь int *p = &k+1, а что происходит затем ?   в первой же итерации он уже установится не в то значение, в которое ты думаешь

Comment: @Nastya то есть выполнится либо этот код (double*)(++p), либо этот (int*)(++p), что сдвинет этот указатель на четыре байта вперед,    а должен сдвинуть на один байт, так как   указывает на переменную типа char, которая занимает один байт

Comment: Использование всякой фигни вместо стандартных макросов из <stdarg> нестандартно и непереносимо, и вообще - UB. Написать можно, но гарантий, что оно будет работать еще где-то, никаких. (Можно подсказать, что, как я понимаю, надо для `char` и `int` двигать указатель на 4 байта, для double - на 8, но это если и сработает будлет кардинально неверной подсказкой!!)

Comment: Ну вот откуда берутся кретины-преподаватели с такими заданиями - *Нужно написать вариант функции без <stdarg.h>*?! Этот способ для каждого компилятора может быть своим (если существует).

Comment: Я как-то писал собственную библиотеку `varargs`. Это отнюдь не учебное задание. Собственный стек для каждых потоков. Ссылки на следующий элемент стека. Добавление аргументов функцией. И очищение стека. Кошмар...

Comment: Может я что-то непонимаю, почему такая зацикленность на передаче параметров через переменный список параметров? Почему нельзя выделить память, сложить в нее все данные и передать в функцию указатель на выделенную память (ну и возможно на использованный размер буффера, чтобы не ловить конец списка по магическим значениям)?

Comment: @tutankhamun, кмк, или не правильно понята задача, или препод идиот, потому что эта задача ни теоретической, ни практической пользы не имеет. Даже решению на C++ через шаблоны не место в проде

Comment: @Arenoros Согласен насчет пользы. Насчет препода, даже если он идиот, он обычно подразумевает достижение цели каким-либо образом. Я склоняюсь к тому что скорее всего с формулировкой/пониманием задачи проблема возникла

Comment: Точно что не Си++?

Answer (score 6):

Как я уже сказал выше в комментариях под вопросом, написать функцию с переменным количеством аргументов без использования средств, предоставляемых заголовочным файлом [`<stdarg.h>`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdarg.h) переносимым способом невозможно. Имейте это в виду, и, если нужно, покажите этот ответ своему преподователю.

---

А теперь смотрите, почему это не возможно с *теоретической* и почти всегда невозможно c *практической* сторон.

### Теоретическая сторона

С теоретической стороны это невозможно, т. к. этого не позволяет стандарт языка C. В стандарте сказано, что размещение параметров при вызове функции неспецифицированно:

> <sup>9</sup> Each parameter has automatic storage duration; its identifier is an lvalue.<sup>166)</sup> The layout of the storage for parameters is unspecified.
>
> — ISO/IEC 9899:2017 N2176 §6.9.1

Это значит, что способ передачи аргументов в функцию полностью зависит от реализации и делать какие-либо предположения о том, как параметры передаются в функцию — бессмысленно.

### Практическая сторона

Теперь рассмотрим практическую сторону. Как я уже сказал, способ передачи аргументов в функцию зависит от реализации. Проблема в том, что реализаций может быть много. Очень много. Под реализацией понимается, как минимум:

- компилятор
- *hosted* или *freestanding* среда исполнения<sup>1</sup>;
- целевая архитектура ([ISA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture));
- [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface), в частности — *соглашения о вызове* (*[calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention)*);
- …

Количество всех возможных комбинаций очень велико. Причем для каждой такой комбинации код, в общем случае, будет разным. Придется учитывать особенности каждого ABI, и не факт, что ABI позволит получить значения аргументов таким «грязным» способом. Вынужден признать, что в некоторых обстоятельствах мы *можем решить задачу*, хотя говорить о корректности решения в таких случаях не приходится.

### Конкретные примеры

Допустим, что мы заранее знаем, каким компилятором, под какую архитектуру и с каким ABI будет компилироваться программа. Например, это будет GCC, Intel 64<sup>2</sup> и [System V ABI](https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/x86-64-psABI-1.0.pdf) (x86_64 psABI).

Тогда мы сталкиваемся с тем, что в такой конфигурации в *принципе не можем решить поставленную задачу*. Почему? Потому что, согласно System V ABI, вещественные значения передаются в функцию не через стек, а через специальные регистры `%xmm0`−`%xmm7`. А, как вы знаете, язык C не позволяет обращаться к конкретным регистрам процессора.

Тогда, снова сделаем допущение, что нам повезло немного больше и мы компилируем программу под IA-32<sup>3</sup>, [i386 System V ABI](https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/intel386-psABI-1.1.pdf), i386 GNU/Linux. Согласно такому ABI, параметры передаются через стек и нам настолько повезло, что мы даже знаем их конкретное размещение (см. раздел *Function Calling Sequence*)!

Напишем код, который вызывал бы нужную нам функцию:

```
#include <stdio.h>

double sum(unsigned int, ...);

int
main(void)
{
    printf("%f\n", sum(3, 1.0, 2.0, 16.0));
}
```

И проверим нужные смещения отладчиком:

```
>>> print *((unsigned int *) ($esp + 0))
$1 = 3
>>> print *((double *) ($esp + 4))
$2 = 1
>>> print *((double *) ($esp + 12))
$3 = 2
>>> print *((double *) ($esp + 20))
$4 = 16
```

Отлично! Теперь можем написать реализацию функцию `sum`:

```
double
sum(unsigned int n, ...)
{
    double s = 0.0;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        double *p = ((unsigned char *) &n) + sizeof(unsigned int) + sizeof(double) * i;
        s += *p;
    }

    return s;
}
```

---

<sup>1)</sup> За подробностями обращайтесь к разделу «5.1.2 Execution Environement» стандарта C17.

<sup>2)</sup> Эту ISA часто называют x64, x86_64 или x86-64. Скорее всего, процессор вашего компьютера реализует именно эту архитектуру.

<sup>3)</sup> Эту ISA также называют x32, i386 или Intel-386.

Comment: А где в вопросе ограничение на C?

Comment: @Arenoros, метка [c], нет?

Answer (score 3):

**ЭТО НЕ ОТВЕТ!!**
Просто в комментарий не втиснуться. Вот как VC++ 2017 обрабатывает вызов вашей функции в 64-разрядном приложении:

```
; 9    :     SumIntDouble(6, 'i', 1, 'd', 2.0, 'i', 3, 'd', 4.0, 'i', 5, 'd', 6.0);

    movsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR __real@4018000000000000
    mov edx, 105                ; 00000069H
    movsd   QWORD PTR [rax-24], xmm0
    movsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR __real@4010000000000000
    mov DWORD PTR [rax-32], 100         ; 00000064H
    mov DWORD PTR [rax-40], 5
    lea r9d, QWORD PTR [rdx-5]
    mov DWORD PTR [rax-48], 105         ; 00000069H
    lea r8d, QWORD PTR [rdx-104]
    movsd   QWORD PTR [rax-56], xmm0
    lea ecx, QWORD PTR [rdx-99]
    movsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR __real@4000000000000000
    mov DWORD PTR [rax-64], 100         ; 00000064H
    mov DWORD PTR [rax-72], 3
    mov DWORD PTR [rax-80], 105         ; 00000069H
    movsd   QWORD PTR [rax-88], xmm0
    call    ?SumIntDouble@@YAXHZZ           ; SumIntDouble
```

Вот и крутись тут, как знаешь :)

В 32-разрядном попроще:

```
; 9    :     SumIntDouble(6, 'i', 1, 'd', 2.0, 'i', 3, 'd', 4.0, 'i', 5, 'd', 6.0);

    movsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR __real@4018000000000000
    sub esp, 8
    movsd   QWORD PTR [esp], xmm0
    movsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR __real@4010000000000000
    push    100                 ; 00000064H
    push    5
    push    105                 ; 00000069H
    sub esp, 8
    movsd   QWORD PTR [esp], xmm0
    movsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR __real@4000000000000000
    push    100                 ; 00000064H
    push    3
    push    105                 ; 00000069H
    sub esp, 8
    movsd   QWORD PTR [esp], xmm0
    push    100                 ; 00000064H
    push    1
    push    105                 ; 00000069H
    push    6
    call    ?SumIntDouble@@YAXHZZ           ; SumIntDouble
    add esp, 64                 ; 00000040H
```

Видите? А это один и тот же компилятор...

У вас, кстати, какой?

**Update**

Для VC++ 2017 **32-разрядное приложение** (для 64-разрядного работать не будет) вот такое работает:

```
void SumIntDouble(int, ...);

int main(void)
{
    SumIntDouble(6, 'i', 1, 'd', 2.0, 'i', 3, 'd', 4.0, 'i', 5, 'd', 6.0);
    getchar(); getchar();
}

void SumIntDouble(int k, ...)
{
    double sum = 0;
    double a = 0; // числитель
    double b = 0; // знаменатель
    int* p = &k;
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        char c = *(++p);
        switch (c) {
        case'i': {
            p++;
            if (i % 2 == 0)
                a += *p;
            else
                b += *p;
            break;
        }
        case'd': {
            p++;
            if (i % 2 == 0)
                a += *(double*)p;
            else
                b += *(double*)p;
            p++;
            break;
        }
        }
    }
    sum = a / b;
    printf(" Сумма: %lf\n", sum);
}
```

Comment: У меня VS 2019. Написала функцию с использованием только указателей, но для параметров одного типа - у меня компилирует нормально, но нужна версия для данных разного типа. Подозреваю, что напутала что-то с указателями) Уже поняла, что без stdarg.h писать - извращение, но преподаватель задал задание в целях практики использования указателей, поэтому написать все-таки нужно)

Comment: Ну, я добавил для VC++ 2017, думаю, сработает и на 2019 - но только в 32-разрядном варианте... Но преподаватель - если задает такое - чудак с большой буквы мэ... Относитесь с большой осторожностью к тому, чему он вас будет учить... Если не секрет, это где такой водится?

Comment: Мне кажется, или gcc издевается? https://ideone.com/1gdHCz - почему аргументы не по порядку??

Answer (score 0):

если бы не нужно было перемешивать аргументы можно было бы сделать проще.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdio>

struct Null {};
Null calc(){ return Null{}; }

template<class F, class S>
struct Sum {
    F first;
    S second;

    auto operator+(Null next) { return *this; }
    template<class F1, class S1>
    auto operator+(Sum<F1, S1>&& next) {
        first += next.first;
        second +=  next.second;
        return *this;
    }
    auto res() { return first/second; }
};
template<class T1, class T2> Sum(const T1&, const T2&) -> Sum<T1, T2>; 

template<typename T1,
         typename T2,
         typename... Other>
auto calc(T1 x1, T2 x2, Other... args) {
    return (Sum{x1, x2} + calc(args...));
}

int main(){
    auto sum = calc(12.2, 2.3, 3.0, 4.4, (char)5, 6);
    printf("%f", sum.res());
    return 0;
}
```

Плюсы:

- Можно складывать любые типы, достаточно описать оператор `+` для него
- Если аргументов нечётное количество ошибка будет известна на compiletime
- Если аргументы известны в compiletime то и всё вычисление будет в compiletime [1].

Минусы:

- Тип у sum.first и sum.second зависит от первых двух параметров, т.е если первыми будут int то и все вычисление будет усечено до int.

---

[1] Этот пример компилируется буквально в пару строчек:

```
calc():
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
.LC1:
        .string "%f"
main:
        sub     rsp, 8
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC1
        mov     eax, 1
        movsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
        call    printf
        xor     eax, eax
        add     rsp, 8
        ret
.LC0:
        .long   3415682653
        .long   1073312485
```

Comment: Комментарии к минусу будут?

Comment: Как бы. вопрос о си

Comment: @ヒミコ, как бы в универе не делают между ними разницы и это единственный возможный вариант реализации в заданных условиях

Answer (score -1):

анука попробуй вот так 
я не запускал так что может не работать )

```
char *address = (char*)(&k + 1);
char type;
double a, b;
int intData;
double doubleData;

for(int i = 0; i < k; i++)
{
    type = *address;
    address++;

    switch(type)
    {
        case 'i':
            intData = *(int*)(address);
            if (i % 2 == 0)
                a += (double)intData;
            else
                b += (double)intData;

            address += sizeof(int);
            break;

        case 'd': 
            doubleData = *(double*)(address);
            if (i % 2 == 0)
                a += doubleData;
            else
                b += doubleData;

            address += sizeof(double);
            break;

    }
}
```

Comment: Неа, не работает( Исправила ошибки в своем коде, но все равно программа просто виснет, уже не понимаю, что не так (код выше)

Comment: @Jezz   в каком месте виснет ??   какая строчка

Comment: Исправила, все хорошо, спасибо)

Comment: @Jezz   что исправила ?? ты ж говоришь моё не пашет